# Rails 3 and Webrat : wrong redirections

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, webrat

I can't do my tests because something is not really working.

The code is in this pastie here: http://pastie.org/1506941

i got a simple login which i want to test. But every time webrat does the POST to /user_session i get to /account_finder (which is only redirected if no subdomain is given) instead of the target controller after a login.

Ruby 1.9.2
Rails 3.0.3 
Webrat 0.7.3

Can someone give me an advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but I'm using cucumber now. It is working there.